# Failed to load scss with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass-loader

I'm using webpack, and I want to load scss file in my JavaScript. (Or if it can be separate, it also fine).

This is my webpack config:

```
"use strict";
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + '/src',
    entry: './js/index.js',
    output: {
        path: './build',
        filename: 'js/app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        root: [
            path.resolve('./src/js'),
            path.resolve('./src/scss')
        ],
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: 'html/**', to: `${__dirname}/build/html`, flatten: true },
            { from: 'images/**', to: `${__dirname}/build/image`, flatten: true }
        ])
    ]
};
```

this is my files list:

- src/html/index.html -> build/html/index.html (WORKED)
- src/images/**       -> build/images/** (WORKED)
- src/js/index.js     -> build/js/app.bundle.js (WORKED)
- src/scss/**         -> build/css/** **(NOT WORKED)**

This is my JavaScript code. I just started project, so not much codes:

```
import "babel-polyfill";
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import moduleA from 'moduleA';
import "view/startup.scss";

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <h1>Helloworld!</h1>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('entry')
);
```

You can see this: **import "view/startup.scss";**
I want to load scss file into my JavaScript, but when I run webpack command, it says:

> ERROR in Loader /Users/.../Desktop/work/my-project/app/node_modules/css/index.js didn't return a function
>    @ ./scss/view/startup.scss 4:14-123

in "resolve" property of webpack config, you can see that I added another root directory for scss, also I loaded sass-loader too, but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

And as I know, with Webpack, including css/scss automatically injects into destination file, so it doesn't matter it needs to be extract as separate file, I just want that this works.

Any help will be very appreciated :)

*** UPDATED ***
code of ./scss/view/startup.scss

```
#startup {
    background-color: #7087d7;
}
```

Comment: What's in `./scss/view/startup.scss` ?

Comment: @Nobert just plain scss code. Do I need to write it?

Comment: @Nobert question updated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error points towards the reason (I highlighted the relevant part):

> ERROR in Loader /Users/.../Desktop/work/my-project/app/node_modules/**css/index.js** didn't return a function @ ./scss/view/startup.scss 4:14-123

When you declare a loader in Webpack, you can leave off the `-loader` suffix (so `css-loader` becomes `css`) *provided that you don't have other modules that may match the suffixless loader name*.

This is where it fails in your case, because you also use the [`css`](https://github.com/reworkcss/css) package, which Webpack tries to use as a loader (and fails, because it's not).

To fix this, use the full loader package name:

```
 loaders : [ "style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader" ]
```

Comment: Thanks robertklep! You saved my life! :)